# Closed form for $\prod\limits_{l=1}^\infty \cos\frac{x}{3^l}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, closed-form, infinite-product, trigonometric-series

Is there any closed form for the infinite product $\prod_{l=1}^\infty \cos\dfrac{x}{3^l}$? I think it is convergent for any $x\in\mathbb{R}$.

I think there might be one because there is a closed form for $\prod_{l=1}^\infty\cos\dfrac{x}{2^l}$ if I'm not wrong.

Comment: Convergence is easy to show - let $a_n$ be the $n^{th}$ partial product, then it's fairly easy to show that $\{a_n\}_{n\ge 1}$ is Cauchy (use $|a_n| \le 1$, and the first few terms of the Taylor expansion of $\cos$). An expression for the product is unlikely. Recall that the calculation of the product in the $2^n$ case relies on the serendipitous fact that $2\cos x \sin x = \sin 2x$, which leads to a simple recursion for the partial products. The identity relating the cosine of an angle to that of its third has a nasty $\cos^3$ term which is hard to absorb into the next term in the product.

Comment: $\sum\cos\frac{x}{2^n}=\frac{\sin x}{x}$, but I do not know of a similar formula in the 3 case.

Comment: $\prod \cos(\pi/3^l) = 0.46627457895504917$ is not recognized by ISC http://isc.carma.newcastle.edu.au/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If we start from
$$ \cos(x) = \prod_{n\geq 0}\left(1-\frac{4x^2}{(2n+1)^2 \pi^2}\right) \tag{1}$$
we have:

$$ \log\cos(x) = -\sum_{n\geq 0}\sum_{m\geq 1}\frac{4^m x^{2m}}{m(2n+1)^{2m} \pi^{2m}}=-\sum_{m\geq 1}\frac{(4^m-1)\zeta(2m)\,x^{2m}}{m\pi^{2m}}\tag{2} $$
hence:
$$ \sum_{l\geq 1}\log\cos\left(\frac{x}{3^l}\right)=-\sum_{m\geq 1}\frac{(4^m-1)\zeta(2m)}{(9^m-1)m\pi^{2m}}x^{2m}\tag{3} $$
and 
$$ \prod_{l\geq 1}\cos\left(\frac{x}{3^l}\right) = \color{red}{\exp\left(-\sum_{m\geq 1}\frac{(4^m-1)\zeta(2m)}{(9^m-1)m\pi^{2m}}x^{2m}\right)}\tag{4}$$

does not simplify much further.

Answer (score 2):

We follow the method of [this](http://www.calpoly.edu/~kmorriso/Research/cosine.pdf) paper, using the Fourier transform.

Following his normalizations,
$$
\hat f (\omega) = \frac{1}{2\pi} \int_{\mathbb R} f(x) e^{-i \omega x} \, dx, \qquad f(x) = \int_{\mathbb R} \hat f(\omega) e^{i \omega x} \, d\omega,
$$
the key facts to be used are:

1. The identity $\cos(bx) = \frac{e^{i b x} + e^{-i b x}}{2}$
2. If $f(x) = e^{ibx}$, then $\hat f(\omega) = \delta_b(\omega)$, the Dirac delta centered at $\omega = b$.
3. The convolution formula $\widehat{fg} = \hat f * \hat g$.
4. The identity $\delta_a * \delta_b = \delta_{a+b}$.

Applying these to your problem,
\begin{align*}
\prod_{k=1}^n \cos\left(\frac{x}{3^k}\right) &= \prod_{k=1}^n \frac{e^{i \frac{x}{3^k}} + e^{-i \frac{x}{3^k}}}{2} \\
\implies \widehat{\prod_{k=1}^n \cos\left(\frac{x}{3^k}\right)} &= \frac{1}{2^n} \left(\delta_{\frac{1}{3^1}} + \delta_{-\frac{1}{3^1}} \right) * \cdots * \left(\delta_{\frac{1}{3^n}} + \delta_{-\frac{1}{3^n}} \right)(\omega) \\
&= \frac{1}{2^n} \sum_{p \in P_n} \delta_p(\omega)
\end{align*}
where $P_n$ is the set of $2^n$ points given by $P_n = \left\{\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{b_k}{3^k} \;\middle|\; b_k \in \{-1,1\} \; \forall k \right\}$. Note that the endpoints of $\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty P_n$ are bounded tightly by $\pm \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{3^k} = \pm \frac{1/3}{1 - 1/3} = \pm \frac{1}{2}$, and every point in $\left[ - \tfrac{1}{2}, \tfrac{1}{2} \right]$ is the limit of some sequence $(p_n)_{n=1}^\infty$, where $p_n \in P_n$. Hence $\tfrac{1}{2^n} \sum_{p \in P_n} \delta_p(\omega)$ tends to the uniform density of total mass $1$ over $\left[ - \tfrac{1}{2}, \tfrac{1}{2} \right]$ as $n\to\infty$, which is given by the indicator function $\chi_{\left[ - \tfrac{1}{2}, \tfrac{1}{2} \right]}(\omega)$:
\begin{align*}
\widehat{\prod_{k=1}^\infty \cos\left(\frac{x}{3^k}\right)} &= \chi_{\left[ - \tfrac{1}{2}, \tfrac{1}{2} \right]}(\omega).
\end{align*}
Taking inverse Fourier transforms, we get
$$
\prod_{k=1}^\infty \cos\left(\frac{x}{3^k}\right) = \int_{\mathbb R} \chi_{\left[ - \tfrac{1}{2}, \tfrac{1}{2} \right]}(\omega) e^{i \omega x} \, d\omega = \int_{-1/2}^{1/2} e^{i \omega x} \, d\omega = \frac{\sin\left(\tfrac{x}{2}\right)}{\tfrac{x}{2}}.
$$

---

UPDATE: here's why the above is *wrong*. The statement that "every point in $\left[ - \tfrac{1}{2}, \tfrac{1}{2} \right]$ is the limit of some sequence $(p_n)_{n=1}^\infty$, where $p_n \in P_n$" is incorrect; in fact, the points belonging to $P = \bigcup_n P_n$ are those which have [balanced ternary](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Balanced_ternary) expansion consisting of the digits $1$ and $-1$ but not $0$. I'm not sure how to better describe $P$, but we'd proceed as before by integrating over $P$ (rather than all of $\left[ - \tfrac{1}{2}, \tfrac{1}{2} \right]$) to compute the inverse Fourier transform yielding the correct answer.

Comment: The solution, say $\varphi$, should satisfy $\varphi\left(3x\right)=\cos\left(x\right)\varphi\left(x\right)$.
Is there a closed-form formula?

Comment: $$\prod_{k\geq 1}\cos\left(\frac{x}{3^k}\right)\neq \text{sinc}\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)$$ because the RHS does not fulfill $\frac{\phi(3x)}{\phi(x)}=\cos x$.

Comment: Following Jon's notation, the union $\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}P_{n}$
is probably not the entire interval, but the middle-third Cantor set
on $\left[-\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2}\right]$.

Comment: You guys are right, what I wrote is not correct, and it's probably because of the hand-wavy step claiming that Dirac distributions approach a uniform distribution

Comment: Sorry for having not mentioned, this question actually comes from calculating the Fourier transform of a Cantor measure. But thanks for your answer anyway and I'm glad to know about the paper you referred.

Answer (score -1):

Let $\displaystyle P=\prod_{i=1}^n\cos\left(\frac x{2^i}\right)$.

$\displaystyle P=\cos\left(\frac x{2}\right)\cos\left(\frac x{4}\right)\cos\left(\frac x{8}\right)\cdots\cos\left(\frac x{2^n}\right)$

$\displaystyle P\sin\left(\frac x{2^n}\right)=\cos\left(\frac x{2}\right)\cos\left(\frac x{4}\right)\cos\left(\frac x{8}\right)\cdots\cos\left(\frac x{2^n}\right)\sin\left(\frac x{2^n}\right)$

$\displaystyle P\sin\left(\frac x{2^n}\right)=\frac12\,\cos\left(\frac x{2}\right)\cos\left(\frac x{4}\right)\cos\left(\frac x{8}\right)\cdots\cos\left(\frac x{2^{n-1}}\right)\sin\left(\frac x{2^{n-1}}\right)$

...

$\displaystyle P\sin\left(\frac x{2^n}\right)=\frac1{2^{n-1}}\,\cos\left(\frac x{2}\right)\sin\left(\frac x2\right)$

$\displaystyle P\sin\left(\frac x{2^n}\right)=\frac1{2^{n}}\,\sin(x)$

$\displaystyle P=\frac{\sin(x)}{2^{n}\sin\left(\frac x{2^n}\right)}$

$\displaystyle \lim_{n\to\infty}P=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\sin(x)}x\frac{2^{-n}x}{\sin\left( 2^{-n}x \right)}=\frac{\sin(x)}x$

However, I am not able to solve the one with $3$ in the denominator.

Comment: The question has 3 in the denominator.

Comment: @anon Sorry, I could not solve that.

Comment: Then it's not clear that this answer is relevant to the question at hand. At best, it indicates that the technique used to show the $\cos(x/2^l)$ version is not applicable to the $\cos(x/3^l)$.

Comment: The review task came back as 5-to-3 votes in favor of deleting this. Not a clear mandate, so I need to make a call myself.... Letting it stay. If I got it right this leads to a bound proving the convergence of OP's product.